# Harry Potter fanfiction where he doesn't get his letter at 11

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

In this story, Harry never got his Hogwarts letter, and Voldemort might have returned or something, somehow, and  Draco, Hermione, Ginny, Luna and Ron, go looking for Harry Potter, to see if he really exists, because they need to be saved from Voldemort, or something like that, it's 8 chapters long.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was Hermione's Hogwarts Crammer for delinquents on the run https://archiveofourown.org/works/7331278/chapters/16653022

> 'You're a wizard, Harry' is easier to hear from a half-giant when you're eleven, rather than from some kids on a tube platform when you're seventeen and late for work.

Comment: Can you explain why it matches, for future viewers? You should also be able to accept your self answer.

Comment: I don't care, my answer links to the story anyway, so they can find out for themselves.

Comment: Except... If the link ever rots, nobody will be able to check, hence why @FuzzyBoots (and myself) strongly encourage you to edit in some quotes from the story (Draco Hermione etc going to look for Harry, etc). Plus this way people don't have to switch between sites to gather the info, making it a better answer.